# Is there any way to change default button color of message dialog in uwp?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I just want to change color of default button "OK" in message dialog

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/56b0b6b3-2111-4205-a0f8-97c17e394a26/changing-default-colors-of-messagedialog?forum=winappswithcsharp) might help you.

Comment: Could swap it for ContentDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of exploration I found it is not possible to customize it. 
But found some interesting thing too as I detailed below:

1.You can add more button or skip default button by add more **UiCommand**.

2.Yes you can change its default button background blue color but it is possible to change in **manifest** file which will set it default color for whole application.

Actually much better to use Content dialog for customization purpose. but above points are also useful in specific requirement.

Comment: thank you for change it just set background by the way > Project / Store / Edit App Manifest, and set the "Background color". just input this #418296 for example